# JavaScript parameter used in arrow function but not declared anywhere in local scope - Twilio function

Tags: javascript, callback, twilio

I'm working on a pre-existing Twilio function and am trying to understand how the following code works. I've tested it a few times, and as long as I send the 'from' phone number any message, I get the response described in the 'body'. However, I'm trying to understand how the 'msg' and 'err' parameters can exist, given they aren't declared elsewhere in the function. Can someone help me understand how these parameters are valid? I'm new to JavaScript and only understand the basics of callbacks and promises.

EDIT: I'm starting to understand the idea more. So the 'then' and 'catch' statements are callbacks that occur after the create() function finishes. Thank you for the answers that helped me understand.

```
  exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  context.getTwilioClient().messages.create({
    to: '+14806484732 ',
    from: '+12133151685',
    body: 'Remember the special today is Shrimp Scampi'
  }).then(msg => {
    callback(null, msg.sid);
  }).catch(err => callback(err));
}
```

Comment: They're passed when `create()` resolves the promise.

Comment: It's similar to the way that parameters are passed to a function run through `array.forEach()`.

Comment: Okay, so the parameters come from the create() call. How exactly do they get passed in? I'm pretty new to promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`err => callback(err)` - this is a declaration of function. single parameter `err`, executing function `callback`

similar situation with

```
.then(msg => { // `msg` is a single parameter of declared function
  callback(null, msg.sid);
}
```

Example

```js
const callback = argument => console.log(argument)
// this line is similar to
// const callback = (argument) => { console.log(argument) }
// also similar to
// function callback(argument) { console.log(argument) }

const func = err => callback(err)
// this line is similar to
// const func = (err) => { callback(err) }
// also similar to
// function func(err) { callback(err) }

func('test')
```

Comment: I see. So it's similar to a lambda from Java, right? But where does the actual value of msg come from. In other words, how does msg get passed into the function?

Comment: `context.getTwilioClient().messages.create(...)` reutrns asonchrouns `Promise`, if and when Promise will be resolved, `then` function `msg => callback(null, msg.sid)` will be executed. Othervise Promise will fail with error, and error will caught with `.catch(err => callback(err))`

Answer (score 0):

The functions given in `then` and `catch` are callbacks that both take a single parameter. Each of these parameters have a specific meaning based on the function documentation, which you can look up. You are, however, free to call them whatever you like if you were to write the callbacks yourself. The names are simply chosen to convey the semantics as clearly as possible.

Thus, they are essentially just parameters of an anonymous function.

I strongly recommend looking into callbacks in Javascript, as they are used everywhere.